# how to target sql server 2008 with EF Core

Tags: ef-core-2.1

Building a razor pages application usign ef core 2.1.1. Development DB server  localDB, target SQL server  SQL 2008 r2.

I get the following error on the target server:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.
>   Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

I suppose the generated SQL code is targeted to SQL server 2012 and up.

How do I force ef core to generate code for SQL server 2008?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

EF Core, or more specifically the underlying driver used when interacting with SQL Server `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` only supports `SQL Server 2012` and onwards. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

One alternative to make your `Skip` and `Take` queries work is to use the below when configuring your `DbContext`

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(connection, opt => opt.UseRowNumberForPaging()));
```

**Update:**

- Row-number paging is **no longer supported**. See: https://aka.ms/AA6h122
- There is a [third-party package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.UseRowNumberForPaging/) to add it back: https://github.com/Rwing/EntityFrameworkCore.UseRowNumberForPaging